# Teamspeak 3 module API "Cannot GET /"

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, whmcs, teamspeak

I am trying to setup a teamspeak 3 module for my WHMCS website.

I've did everything right according to the tutorial.
But I also have an API coded in node that works with the module.
When I access **0.0.0.0:3000** I get the error "Cannot GET /"
My firewall is turned off so it can't be the any port that is blocked.
This is my api.js

```
"use strict";
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('tsdns.sqlite');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config.json');

db.serialize(function() {
  db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zones (id integer primary key, zone varchar(100),target varchar(50))");
});

app.get('/list', function (req, res) {
  if( req.headers.authorization == config.api_key ){
    var zone = req.params.zone;
    db.all("SELECT * FROM zones", function(err, rows) {
      res.send('{"result":"success","message":' + JSON.stringify( rows ) + '}');
    });
  }else{
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.send('{"result":"error","message":"Invalid auth token"}');
  }
});

app.get('/add/:zone/:target', function (req, res) {
  if( req.headers.authorization == config.api_key ){
    var zone = req.params.zone;
    var target = req.params.target;
    var sql = "INSERT INTO zones(zone,target) VALUES(?,?)";
    var stmt = db.prepare(sql,zone,target);
    stmt.run();
    stmt.finalize();
    res.statusCode = 201;
    res.send('{result:"success"}');
  }else{
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.send('{"result":"error","message":"Invalid auth token"}');
  }
});

app.get('/del/:zone', function (req, res) {
  if( req.headers.authorization == config.api_key ){
    var zone = req.params.zone;
    var sql = "DELETE FROM zones WHERE zone =?";
    var stmt = db.prepare(sql,zone);
    stmt.run();
    stmt.finalize();
    res.statusCode = 202;
    res.send('{result:"success"}');
  }else{
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.send('{"result":"error","message":"Invalid auth token"}');
  }
});

app.get('/get/:zone', function (req, res) {
  if( req.headers.authorization == config.api_key ){
    var zone = req.params.zone;
    db.all("SELECT * FROM zones WHERE zone=?",zone, function(err, row) {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.send('{"result":"success","message":' + JSON.stringify( row ) + '}');
    });
  }else{
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.send('{"result":"error","message":"Invalid auth token"}');
  }
});

module.exports = app;
```

And when I try to access e.g http://0.0.0.0:3000/list I get this error
"{"result":"error","message":"Invalid auth token"}"

So something is obviously wrong. I am new to node so I can't figure out what the problem is.

This is my server.js

```
var config = require('./config.json');
var api = require('./api.js');
var tsdns = require('./tsdns');

api.listen(config.api_port,config.api_ip, function () {
  console.log('Api webservice running at %s:%s', config.api_ip, config.api_port);
});

tsdns.listen(config.tsdns_port,config.tsdns_ip, function () {
  console.log('Tsdns running at %s:%s', config.tsdns_ip,config.tsdns_port);
});
```

That is what I am supposed to start when I want the API to run and then it says this.

> C:\Users\Administrator>node server.js 
>    Api webservice running at 0.0.0.0:3000
>    Tsdns running at 0.0.0.0:41144

So it says it is running and I don't recieve any errors, this API doesn't have any error logs either.
This is the API folder
[CLICK HERE TO SEE IT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LchkM.png)

If you want me to share more codes of the API then I will.

Answer (score 0):

There's no GET route for "/", that's why you get that message. The api should only expect requests from your whmcs addon, for example:

```
http://yourdomain.com/get/yourdnszone
```

An auth token must be also sent in the request header.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will look into it.

Comment: Wait a second, you are the one to created this api? If you have any time please help me to make it work.

Comment: I already explained  how the api works. If you are having issues to setup the whmcs adddon that connect with the api you should contact the whmcs addon seller support.

Comment: Well I've had this problem for a long time now, I fixed it once but I don't remember how I fixed it. Here are some details, I might did something wrong. https://gyazo.com/6296a7069b4eb5a55f87213a694df8aa?token=701c02db77fd0ebb17a52ac3d8c996b1 and this one https://gyazo.com/10abae53bd19cc43c64992bc7b9913e4